# how do I properly incorporate arrays into for loops in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, web, switch-statement

I am working on a custom gallery right now, but I cannot seem to get the array of variables to apply during the loop. What am I missing?

Here is the relevant code:

```
var racerImage = ['$("img.ryanthumb")', '$("img.pierthumb")', '$("img.jeremythumb")',
       '$("img.mattthumb")', '$("img.andrewthumb")', '$("img.alanthumb")',
       '$("img.kevinthumb")', '$("img.mikethumb")', '$("img.dougthumb")'];

var showMe= ['showRacer("ryan")\;', 'showRacer("pier")\;',
       'showRacer("jeremy")\;', 'showRacer("matt")\;', 'showRacer("andrew")\;',
       'showRacer("alan")\;', 'showRacer("kevin")\;', 'showRacer("mike")\;', 
       'showRacer("doug")\;'];

for (var i = 0; i < racerImage.length; i++)
{
    racerImage[i].click(function(){
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 1:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 3:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 4:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 5:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 6:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 7:
                showMe[i];
                break;
            case 8:
                showMe[i];
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Basically I am trying to use a for loop to apply the jquery multiple times instead of writing it over and over again. I don't know if I am going about this the right way, but any insights would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the purpose of the switch statement when every case does exactly the same thing?

Comment: [The Daily WTF is not a best practices compendium.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Switched_on_Loops.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended up having three main problems:

1. You have jQuery code strings in the `racerImage` array which end up being just strings, not actual jQuery objects so they don't work.
2. You have function call code strings in the `showMe` array which don't work either.
3. Your value of `i` in the click handler function doesn't work because the event handler happens some time later when the value of `i` is no longer what you want it to be.

To fix those, change the `racerImage` array to just an array of selectors and turn them into jQuery objects when needed in your code.

Change the `showMe` array into an array of names that you can just pass to the `showRacer()` function when needed.

And, you don't need the switch statement at all since `i` is already your index.

```
var racerImage = ["img.ryanthumb", img.pierthumb, "img.jeremythumb",
       "img.mattthumb", "img.andrewthumb" /* and so on */];

var showMe= ["ryan", "pier", "jeremy", "matt" /* and so on */];

for (var i = 0; i < racerImage.length; i++) {
    // create closure to capture the value of i so it is available during the event handler
    (function(i) {
        $(racerImage[i]).click(function(){
            showRacer(showMe[i]);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  `i` was not the correct value because the `for` loop has already ended when the event handler fires.  I've created a closure that captures the value of `i` into an argument on an immediately execution function.

Comment: @Juhana - yeah, I was getting there - I've eliminated the switch statement now.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The thing that had me the most stuck was capturing the value of 'i'. I had tried a few different methods of laying it all out, but this way is the best!

Answer (score 1):

`racerImage[0]` is still just a string which contains the value `$("img.ryanthumb")` - it is not the jQuery object.

What you probably want to do is put the selector value in the string, and then call the jQuery function from there:

```
var racerImage = ['img.ryanthumb', 'img.pierthumb', ...etc...];

...

$(racerImage[i]).click(function(){...});
```

Or you can have your array be the jQuery objects and use them:

```
var racerImage = [$("img.ryanthumb"), $("img.pierthumb"), ...etc...];

...

racerImage[i].click(function(){...});
```

**EDIT**

Thanks Joel for the comment - yep, same problem on `showRacer` - maybe those can be an array of functions:

```
var showMe= [function(){showRacer("ryan");}, function(){showRacer("pier");}, ...etc...];

...

showMe[i]();
```

Comment: And `showMe` is also an array of `showRacer(...)` strings, not function calls, which means `showMe[i]` doesn't execute the expected function call. (And either way, it wouldn't do it, because the array would contain the result of the call - save the parameters instead.)

Comment: jfriend00's answer is also true - the closures will cause problems if not dealt with as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this instead:

```
var racer = ['ryan', 'pier', 'jeremy', 'matt', 'andrew', 'alan', 'kevin', 'mike', 'doug'];
$.each(racer, function(i, v){
  $('img.'+v+'thumb').click(function(){
    showRacer(v);
  })
});
```